# How to initialize static const pointer in a class?

Tags: c++, static, pointers, constants, initialization

```
class School
{
    static const int *classcapacity; 
};
```

This expression is from my exam and it need to get initialized how can i do that ?

Comment: Remember that the pointer is not a constant so can be initialised and assigned normally.  Here the const qualifier simply prevents the data pointed to from being modified through this pointer, i.e. *classcapacity  = 0` is invalid.  You do however need at least a static initialiser.

Answer (score 8):

You can initialize it in your source file, outside of the body of the class, just as you would any other static member variable, i.e.:

```
const int* School::classCapacity(new int(42));
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably this way:

```
class School{
  static const int *classcapacity   ;
};
const int *School::classcapacity = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to initialize it with YOUR_INITIALIZER:

```
class School{ static const int *classcapacity ; } ;
const int* School::classcapacity = YOUR_INITIALIZER;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but in C++11, you'd write:

```
class School
{
   static const int* classcapacity{new int[4]}; // initialize with 4-element array
};
```

Comment: This is still invalid in C++11. Note that the member is non-const.